# Unexpected result from CASE referencing another expression

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

The following statement always returns the result from `st_area(st_buffer(polygon,100))`.

```
select st_Area(polygon) as area,
case when area>100000 then st_area(st_buffer(polygon,500))
else st_area(st_buffer(polygon,100))
end from polygons limit 10;

       area       |     st_area
------------------+------------------
 383287.287473659 | 723738.615102036
 47642.5395246768 | 192575.823383778
  45546.753026985 | 174122.420564731
 435204.455923533 | 725419.735987631
 839954.564052786 | 1268251.88626391
  315213.27742828 | 630424.785088617
 966620.061916605 | 1447647.57269461
 38446.6010009923 | 151584.647252579
 82576.1182937309 | 238095.988431594
 321682.125463567 | 695462.262796463
(10 rows)
```

`st_area` should have been the result of `st_buffer(polygon,500)` when `area>100000` as shown below:

```
     area      |     st_area
------------------+------------------
 383287.287473659 | 2702203.34758147
 47642.5395246768 | 192575.823383778
  45546.753026985 | 174122.420564731
 435204.455923533 | 2507469.89929028
 839954.564052786 | 3568866.96452707
  315213.27742828 | 2453576.33477712
 966620.061916605 | 3953365.12876066
 38446.6010009923 | 151584.647252579
 82576.1182937309 | 238095.988431594
 321682.125463567 | 2628693.69179652
(10 rows)
```

Can someone explain?

Comment: "*The output should have been different*" - and what did you expect?

Comment: This is a bit confusing: area is an alias but also a column name. Use unique names and check what value area actually has.

Comment: Yes, maybe you'd get better results with `when st_Area(polygon) > 100000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't become completely clear from the question (yet), but my educated *guess* is you want this:

```
SELECT st_Area(polygon) AS area  -- or pick some other name!
     , CASE WHEN st_Area(polygon) > 100000
            THEN st_area(st_buffer(polygon,500))
            ELSE st_area(st_buffer(polygon,100)) END AS st_area
FROM   polygons
LIMIT  10;
```

You cannot reference the column alias (name of the ***output*** column) in another item of the same `SELECT` list. You can only reference ***input*** column names. So you have to repeat the expression or use a subquery:

```
SELECT area
     , CASE WHEN area > 100000
            THEN st_area(st_buffer(polygon,500))
            ELSE st_area(st_buffer(polygon,100)) END AS st_area
FROM (SELECT st_Area(polygon) AS area, polygon FROM polygons LIMIT 10) sub;
```

Normally you should get a syntax error immediately. Obviously, there is another column named `area` in your base table. Hence the confusion. Additional wisdom to take away from this:

- It's better to use a name different from any input column when attaching an alias to an output column.
- Always include table definitions in questions. Clarifies *a lot*.

Comment: Thanks, will declare the table definition from now. The problem was that area was a column in the table.